# Does stackexchange provide https access to its API?

Tags: support, bug

Requests I make appear to be redirected back to plain http URLs and the certs seem questionable:

```
% curl -O 'https://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/?key=oxXcnoD51kKE crj7TadaA&tagged=marklogic&body=true&jsonp=stackunderflow._jsonp0&pagesize=3'

curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API 2.0 supports (and requires) SSL. I don't think SSL is supported in API 1.0.

Comment: Just to confirm, v2.0 does support HTTPS access and it is required *for the authentication methods* and recommended for everything else. v1.0 and v1.1 do not support HTTPS access.

Comment: Sure would be nice if the 1.0 or 1.1 docs said as much.